# Telerik - Can I load a report definition from Database

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am working on a WebApplication, and including a [Telerik-Report](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/webforms-report-viewer-controls-overview) in it. The normal way as described works well.

Now I'm trying to load the report definition from a Database, instead of having a file (request from the boss). So far, I've made it work with a temp-file, code is below. But this is far from nice coding.

My question: can I somehow give a string or stream to the report (instead of a file)?

My current code looks like this:

```
private readonly string __path = "C:\\my-temp-directory\\Reports\\";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string contents =  /** Get XML from Database **/;
    File.WriteAllText(__path + "temp.trdx", contents);   // <-- This file I want to omit.
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        this.reportViewer1.ReportSource.Identifier = "temp.trdx";
        this.reportViewer1.ReportSource.IdentifierType = IdentifierType.TypeReportSource;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the report definition is just an XML so it doesn't really matter where you will obtain it from. Looking at the code I think it won't work, because you have a file, but are using TypeReportSource instead of UriReportSource when setting the IdentifierType.

In this scenario I think you should go with the CustomReportSource. The [IdentifierType](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/t-telerik-reportviewer-html5-webforms-identifiertype) can be TypeReportSource, UriReportSource and CustomReportSource. The first two won't work in your case, because you don't know the report type and you also do not want to save it to a file. A CustomReportSource will allow you to put your own logic that will fetch the report from the database and send it to the engine. Actually there is a docs article that fits exactly your scenario:
[How to Implement a Custom Report Source Resolver](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/telerik-reporting-rest-custom-report-resolver)

Comment: This is indeed what I ended up doing. Thanks.